# How to prevent auto-closing of Tomcat on starting from Jenkins job?

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, jenkins

I am trying to start Tomcat in my Jenkins job on a slave machine. 
I start Jenkins slave manually by opening slave-agent.jnlp

This is what I tried in Execute Windows Batch Command:

```
call C:\tomcat\bin\startup.bat
```

Tomcat starts on running the build and the build is marked successful but then Tomcat auto closes after few seconds.

Comment: Did you check tomcat log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **[Jenkins Process Tree Killer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller)** in action. This is by design. You can either disable it globally for the whole Jenkins (not recommended) by starting Jenkins with extra parameter
`-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true`.

For Windows environment, you can use the **[`at`](http://ss64.com/nt/at.html)** command to schedule start of Tomcat (with 1 sec delay).

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Add the below environment variable to shell script, this also will fix the issue:

```
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```