# why doesn't jenkins start my java program?

Tags: java, jenkins

This is extremely annoying but I have a script launch.sh like:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
java -jar foo.jar &
```

If I run it by hand, my java program starts up. However in Jenkins I configured that just does execute shell: $HUDSON_HOME/launch.sh >& out

I see from out file that it looks like it started java, but when I do a ps I don't see it there. How do I configure jenkins appropriately?

Comment: Did you check logs?   Try printing `which java` and `java -version`..

Comment: Why are you running `bash` with `-x`? Does have `launch.sh` have the execute bit set? Also, run the `java` command with `nohup`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent auto-closing of Tomcat on starting from Jenkins job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193444/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-tomcat-on-starting-from-jenkins-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

add

```
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

to shell script